# Online game with Ruby

Tags: ruby, websocket, nodes

I wonder if it is possible to make an online multiplayer game with Ruby. Is it good to choose Ruby for this? Or is Node.Js better than Ruby for this case?

Comment: This a typical off-topic question here.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible to implement an online multiplayer game with Ruby. Specially in the age of WebSocket.

[Here](http://jargon.io/joeyschoblaska/rails-5-chess-with-action-cable-websockets) ([GitHub](https://github.com/joeyschoblaska/rails5chess)) is an example implimentation of a multiplayer chess game with Ruby on Rails 5 and its new feature Action Cable (Rails API for WebSocket).